# How to save job info (qstat) in SGE when submitting to qsub?

Tags: linux, cluster, portable-batch-system

When submitting a job, I am able to provide `qsub` with the path for the standard output and the standard error.

On the other side, while my job 12345 is running, I can access to extra info related to it by using `qstat -j 12345`.

My question is if there is a way to set a path in `qsub` to automatically record the same kind of information provided by `qstat` into a file?

Answer (score 1):

It is a primitive solution but you can get the info:

```
 qstat -j 12345 > 12345.txt
```

You can get some info with:

```
qacct -j 12345
```

but the path for outputs is not there.